# How to change the background color in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to change the background color for the text area. I am using Minamaze theme.

Tried changing the background of textarea, but it didn't help.. Tried clearing the cache as well

Need some guidance..

The website is quantgreeks.com, I want to change the white background behind the text.

Comment: just add a class in textarea and write css property for that class.

Comment: Have you tried changing `input[type=text],input[type=email],textarea` in `wp-content/themes/minamaze/style.css`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your style sheet find:

```
#content {
  clear:both;
  margin:0;
  padding:20px 10px;
}
```

and add a background color to it. For example:

```
#content {
  background-color:#000000;
  clear:both;
  margin:0;
  padding:20px 10px;
}
```